# how to increase ajax/jquery loading time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, response

I just shows an image "loading.gif" while my page is sending ajax request. But i get the response very fast so that the loading image is not visible, it lasts only for less than a second. I just want to control and increase the response time. in order to visible the loading image at least for 2 seconds. Is there any way?

Comment: _please_ don't limit user's waiting time because you want to show a loading screen, rather only show it once the user has waited more than a second or so...

Comment: I know its bad practice.. But i have to do it because my boss asked me to do so. what to do then :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

```
setTimeout(function() { /* Your Code */ }, 2000);
```

(This will wait two seconds before doing the ajax request.)

[Try in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQxbK/34/)

Answer (score 0):

use a counter that starts at 2 and is decremented after 1 second

```
var counter = 2;
function decrement() {
if (--counter == 0) {
 $('#loader').hide();
}
}
 setTimeout(decrement, 1000);
 $.ajax(..., complete: decrement);
```

Comment: This delays the display of the loader, not of the actual AJAX. OP seems to want the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Trickier to know the right solution without you showing us the code... try:

```
  $.ajax({
    ...,
    success: function (image_url) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#loading').html('<img src="' + image_url + '" />');
        }, 3000);
    },
   ...});
```